# React Router is not redirecting on Login and on Logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I've just few days of knowledge of React Router and I'm trying to let it work but evidently I'm missing something. I've followed [the tutorial](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) on the docs but I'm not having any luck.

This are my classes:

**App.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        page: 'login'
    }

    this.handleOnLogout = this.handleOnLogout.bind(this);
}

handleOnLogout(callback) {
    UserDAO.logout().then(() => {
        callback();
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Navbar onLogout={this.handleOnLogout}/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => 
            UserDAO.isLoggedIn ? (
                <Component {...props}/>
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/login",
                    state: { from: props.location }
                }}
                />
            )
        }
    />
)
}
```

**LoginPage.js**

```
handleOnLogin(email, password, positive, negative) {
    let self = this;
    UserDAO.login(email, password).then(user => {
        console.log("Successfully logged in as user #" + user.id);
        positive("Successfully logged in, you'll be soon redirected to the homepage.");
        setTimeout(() => { self.setState({redirectToReferrer: true }) }, 500 );
    }).catch( error => {
        console.log("Error logging in with email/password auth: " + error);
        negative("Error logging in with email/password auth: " + error);
    });
}

render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;

    if (UserDAO.isLoggedIn || redirectToReferrer) return <Redirect to={from} />;

    return (
        <div className="login-page">
            <div className="container d-flex align-items-center">
                <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-6">
                        <LoginForm onLogin={this.handleOnLogin}
                            onForgotPassword={() => { this.setState({ showForgotPasswordModal: true }); } }
                            onResendActivation={() => { this.setState({ showResendActivationModal: true }); } }/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ResendActivationModal show={this.state.showResendActivationModal} enabled onClose={this.closeResendActivationModal}/>
            <ForgotPasswordModal show={this.state.showForgotPasswordModal} enabled onClose={this.closeForgotPasswordModal}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Navbar.js**

```
const Navbar = withRouter(
({ history, onLogout }) => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
            <a className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">MANA</a>
            <ul className="navbar-nav px-3">
                {UserDAO.isLoggedIn &&
                <li className="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <LinkButton className="nav-link" onClick={() => {
                        onLogout(() => { history.push("/"); console.log(history); })
                    }} href="#">Log out</LinkButton>
                </li>}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}
);
```

UserDAO maintain the auth variables and its methods return promises for login and logout (I'm using MongoDB Stitch Browser SDK).

Login and Logout methods are working: after login if I refresh the page it loads the private route, after clock on logout -> refresh -> then I get the login page. I want it to do this without manual refresh.

I want to do following a good design guideline, but it's almost identical to [the official tutorial](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) but it doesn't work.

### Edited

I added some logging before the `<Redirect/>` in the `LoginPage` for the comment of @c-chavez and it get to me this:

[image]

Don't know why it prints twice.

Comment: Once handleOnLogin finishes, and your state is updated, could you print in your `render()` function what `UserDAO.isLoggedIn` and `redirectToReferrer` values are, before that redirection is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was all a my mistake:

in my UserDAO library I exported a variable in this way:

```
export var isLoggedIn = client.auth.isLoggedIn
```

so it return always the same value of the variable that was when the library was imported.

But I want it to be updated every time, so I changed it to:

```
export function isLoggedIn() {
    return client.auth.isLoggedIn;
}
```

And it works!

Thank you all.
Fell free to answer again and correct everything in my design way.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
```

Into:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
```

And, you can [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) like this:

```
if (UserDAO.isLoggedIn || redirectToReferrer) return <Redirect to='dashboard' />;
```

For this question:

> Don't know why it prints twice.

Thing is, when you do this:

```
const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
```

for sure `this.props.location.state` exists. It should be your current path, which is `'/login'` I imagine. Since it will try to redirect to `'/login'` again after it logs you in (which is handled by your router), you render the same page, and thus render the second message with both variables set to `false`.

I wouldn't trust much on that `DAO` you have to handle the state of the user in the app. I would use either cookies, session, redux, or something that does this for sure.